# Ubuntu software centre - accessing the installed programs

Tags: unity, unity-dash, installed-programs

I have just installed Ubuntu along with Windows 7. I'm eager and excited to explore the Ubuntu OS. I have found some free developer tools for Biological application and installed them. Unlike in windows, I was not sure how to access the installed programs. Help me with that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

press the super button on your keyboard (the windows button) and then in the search bar search for your new installs